# https can affect to existing http protocol driven API if we implement

Tags: apache, https

We have web site and API and their URL as http://example.com/?api=xxxxxxxxx
suppose we apply https on our domain and server then it would effect our existing web sites and API and can both protocol can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **switching to HTTPS** may potentially affect your existing API customers. However, it depends on:

1. Whether you'll force HTTPS or not
2. How developers interacts with your API

If you force HTTPS, you'll likely setup a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. If the clients are not designed to follow redirects (in general simple clients are not), then your customers will start noticing 301 or 302 redirect status codes rather than 200.

In this case, the option could be to add HTTPS and deprecate HTTP. Keep HTTP and HTTPS in parallels for a while, long enough to inform your customers to move to the HTTPS version.

Comment: actually our some client insist us to provide https URL, so we are planing to apply https

Comment: if we apply https on server level then both protocol would work fine. I means   http://example.com/?api-xxxxxxxx   and  https://example.com/?api-xxxxxxxx

Comment: Yes, as I mention you can keep running http and https in parallel.

Comment: Thanks bro for help... God bless you